# Type Error 'Can't read properties of undefined' - Accessing API in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json, api

Building a Weather app in React JS using OpenWeatherMapAPI.  What I am trying to do is render dynamic backgrounds based on the response of the API.

The end point for the data I'm looking for is 'data.weather[0].main' and it will show the text 'Clear', 'Cloudy', 'Rain', etc... I will then pass the value through as a prop to my styled component to render the corresponding image. This is where I am getting the error: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0').

I know this is because it is a nested child in the JSON doc.  All the first levels work such as "data.main" or "data.timezone".

I have tried the following and still get the same error:

console.log(data?.weather[0] ? data.weather[0].main : '')

```
const Weather = ({data}) => {

    // Error here
    console.log(data?.weather[0] ? data.weather[0].main : '')
    
    return (

        // Error here
        <StyledContainer bg={data.weather[0].main}>
            <Title>Style me</Title>
            <Heading>{data.name}</Heading>
        </StyledContainer>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) can be used on arrays too...

```
console.log(data?.weather?.[0].main ?? "")
```